# Fontspec: white space in itshape

Tags: xetex, fontspec

The standard font type of my company is Agenda, but when I load this font with `fontspec` using XeTeX, white horizontal space is introduced at certain places. I guess it is a problem with ligatures but I don't find a solution.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Agenda}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\textit{\lipsum[1]}

\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: wow. without the font it is not possible to test, but it looks quite broken. Did you try with lualatex?

Comment: It's rather suspicious that the extra space -- which looks like it has a fixed width -- always occurs between the letters "et", and only in italic.  I'd suspect something amiss in the font kerning settings.